# Python Script uses different IP address than postman on same machine

Tags: python, python-requests, postman, ip

I am using an API Request in a python script that makes requests against an API that needs IP whitelisting.

Naturally I'am getting the error IP not allowed when executing a request against this API.

But after IP whitelisting my laptops IP address I'm still getting the same error.

What have I tried?

I checked my own IP address and added it to the list of allowed IP addresses.

Now I tested the execution of the request again and I'm still getting the IP not allowed error.

So I tried to execute the same request using Postman and it worked!

To double check I removed the IP Address again from the list and checked again. Accordingly I was getting IP not allowed error as expected.

So now my issue is the request in my python script seems to use a different IP address than Postman, as I can execute the request using Postman but not with my Python Script.

Do you have any ideas what error I'm making? Is there any way to check which IP address is used to make the outbound API Call?

Comment: Can you share the code you're using to make the request? Also, could it be possible that the error comes from the way you're making the request, and not your IP? It seems unlikely python can use another IP address than Postman, unless I guess you have some weird proxy/VPN setup

Comment: Using python script, try getting ip address by requesting `http://httpbin.org/ip` . 
and whitelist ip from the response.